# On the physical interpretation of Dirac delta distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, regularization

The original purpose of Dirac was to make up the eigenstate of the position operator $\hat X$.
Now, quantum states are complex-valued functions in the Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
The main point is... $\delta$ is not a function. It can't be associated with a (unique) norm, since Schwartz space is just a Fréchet space, not Banach.

Therefore the probabilistic interpretation of it as a wave function, $|\delta|^2$, is non-sense, and still at some point I will *for sure* see a particle *somewhere*.

So... what is the correct way to look at it?

Comment: I would suggest looking up [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) and the references given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators with purely continuous spectra - such as $\hat X$ - do not have any eigenstates.  The $\delta$-distribution serves as a *generalized* eigenstate, providing a formalization of $|x\rangle$ and $\langle x|$ which are extremely useful computational tools, despite the fact that they do not themselves correspond to physically realizable states.

> [...] at some point I will for sure see a particle somewhere.

This is reflected in the fact that the probability of measuring the particle  somewhere is $1$; this doesn't require the existence of position eigenstates.

---

> Using Born's rule the probability of obtaining the result $a$ from observable $A$ over a state $\psi$ is $\langle \psi|P_a|\psi\rangle$, where $P_a$ projects in the $a$-eigenspace of $A$. But in this case there is no eigenspace, for there are no proper eigenstates, so... ?

The map $\mu_A$, which associates a measurement outcome to the corresponding projection operator, is called a [projection-valued measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure).  By measurement outcome, I mean a (Borel-measurable) subset $E\subseteq \mathbb R$ which could consist of a single value - e.g. $\mu_A(\{a\})= P_a$, in your notation - or multiple distinct values, e.g. $\mu_A(\{a,b,c\}) = P_a+P_b+P_c$.

If the spectrum of the operator $A$ is purely continuous, then the projection $\mu_A(\{a\})=0$ for any individual point $a\in \mathbb R$.  Case in point, the PVM associated to the position operator is simply
$$\mu_X(E) = \chi_E \mathbb I \qquad \chi_E(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & x\in E \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

where $\chi_E$ is the indicator function on $E$ and $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator.  As a result, if the state of the system corresponds to some wavefunction $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, the probability of measuring $\hat X$ to lie in $E$ is given by

$$\mathrm{Prob}_\psi(\hat X,E) := \frac{\langle \psi|\mu_X(E)|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle} = \frac{\int_\mathbb R \psi^*(x) \chi_E(x) \psi(x) \mathrm dx}{\int_\mathbb R \psi^*(x)\psi(x)\mathrm dx}$$
$$ = \frac{\int_E |\psi(x)|^2 \mathrm dx}{\int_\mathbb R |\psi(x)|^2\mathrm dx}$$

Comment: Ok but then... what gives me the probability of finding the particle at some point if I can't compute expectation values?

Comment: @ric.san I'm not sure what you mean.  Why can't you compute expectation values?

Comment: Using Born's rule the probability of obtaining the result $a$ from observable $A$ over a state $\psi$ is $\langle \psi | P_a | \psi \rangle$, where $P_a$ projects in the $a$-eigenspace of $A$. But in this case, for $A = \hat X $ there is no eigenspace, for there are no proper eigenstates, so... ?

Comment: @ric.san I have expanded my answer to cover your follow-up question.

Comment: Please review my edit in case I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, that was a typo. Thank you for your edit.